# How to get value from data structure in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a table and I am using SQL Server as follow:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | /F10749180509 1/TOYOTA TSUSHO ASIA PACIFIC PTE. L 1/TD. 2/600 NORTH BRIDGE ROAD HEX19 01, P 3/SG/ARKVIEWSQUARE SINGAPORE 188778 |
| 2 | /0019695051 1/PT ASURANSI ALLIANZ LIFE 1/INDONESIA 2/ALLIANZ TWR 16FL JL.HRRASUNA SAID 3/ID/JAKARTA |

As you can see on the table, I need to find Country code from field value. The country code can be found in string after "3/". The example from the first row, I need to get "SG" after 3/ and the second row I need to get "ID" after 3/ and so on. Actually If I copy the first data from value field to notepad, the data separated by new line. The data will be like:

```
/F10749180509
1/TOYOTA TSUSHO ASIA PACIFIC PTE. L
1/TD.
2/600 NORTH BRIDGE ROAD HEX19 01, P
3/SG/ARKVIEWSQUARE SINGAPORE 188778
```

Please help to find the query to get country code. Thank you

Comment: Your previous question shows you how to do this sort of string manipulation. Please use the information people are giving you to learn and have a go rather than expecting us to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to use `PATINDEX` here along with `SUBSTRING`.  Assuming that the country code would always be exactly two uppercase letters, we can try:

```sql
SELECT val, SUBSTRING(val, PATINDEX('% [0-9]/[A-Z][A-Z]/%', val) + 3, 2) AS country_code
FROM yourTable
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX to get the data.

```sql
declare @table table(number int, val varchar(8000))

insert into @table 
values
(1, '/F10749180509 1/TOYOTA TSUSHO ASIA PACIFIC PTE. L 1/TD. 2/600 NORTH BRIDGE ROAD HEX19 01, P 3/SG/ARKVIEWSQUARE SINGAPORE 188778')

select substring(val,charindex('3/',val,1)+2,2) from @table
```

> SG